# Printing table name from MYSQL using Golang

Tags: mysql, go

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "database/sql"
        _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

)

type Tag struct {
        Table_name string `json:"table_name"`
}

func main() {
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:roadrunner@tcp(172.31.16.82:10002)/quote_data")
        if err != nil {
                //panic.(err.Error())
                fmt.Println("Connected Fail")
        }
        fmt.Println("Connected")
        defer db.Close()
        result, err1 := db.Query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table' AND table_schema='quote_data'")
        if err1 != nil {
                panic(err1.Error())
        }
        fmt.Println("Showing Tables",result)
        for results.Next() {
                var tag Tag
                err1 = results.Scan(&tag.Table_name)
                if err1 != nil {
                        panic(err.Error())
                }
                log.Printf(tag.Table_name)
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, what is your question? Could you provide more details about your idea?

Comment: The database `information_schema` is not case insensitive, so change `table_type = 'base table'` to `table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`.

Answer (score 2):

you must add type db with table_name to initialize database table

```
type Tag struct {
        Table_name string `db:"table_name" json:"table_name"`
}
```